# Asp.Net VB ajax access request data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

When the user clicks an item the posts product information on the selected item in JSON format, i need to access the JSON data at the requested url, can anyone help me do that?

```
$("[id*='btnProductAdd']").click(function (event) {
    var ProductId = $(this).closest(".product-btn").find("[id*='ProductId']").val();
    AddProduct(81, ProductId);
});

function AddProduct(UserId, ProductId) {

    var ProductInfo = {
        userid: UserId,
        productid: ProductId
    }

    var Url = 'http://mydomain.co.uk/admin/Search.UserProductAdd';

    $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: ProductInfo,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {


        },
        error: function onXmlError() {
            $('#data').html('Sorry we cannot retreive any data currently, please refresh the page.');
        }
    });
}
```

UPDATE
There seems to be a little confusion so just to explain further...it's not on a different domain. I just need help on accessing the data that my code posts to the page /admin/Search.UserProductAdd, which is ASP.NET VB 4.5. I've done it using GET before but not POST, i used the below for GET:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class htmlreturn
    Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext) Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        Dim requestHttp As HttpRequest = context.Request
        Dim response As HttpResponse = context.Response    

        Dim UserId As Integer = requestHttp.QueryString("User_Id")
        Dim RowNo As Integer = requestHttp.QueryString("rno")
        Dim RowStart As Integer = requestHttp.QueryString("rstart")
        Dim HostDomain As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host


        Dim ConnSql As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
        ConnSql.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnSql").ConnectionString()

        Dim cmdSelect As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        cmdSelect.Connection = ConnSql
        cmdSelect.CommandText = "spUserProductsTest"
        cmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@User_Id", SqlDbType.Int, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = UserId
        cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@RowNumber", SqlDbType.Int, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = RowNo
        cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@RowStart", SqlDbType.Int, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = RowStart

        Dim daSelect As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
        daSelect.SelectCommand = cmdSelect

        Dim dsSelect As DataSet = New DataSet()
        daSelect.Fill(dsSelect, "Select")

        cmdSelect.Dispose()
        ConnSql.Close()


        Dim iRows As Integer = dsSelect.Tables("Select").Rows.Count

        Dim ProductHtml As String = ""


        If (dsSelect.Tables.Count > 0) And (dsSelect.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then

            For i = 0 To iRows - 1

                Dim CategoryId As String = dsSelect.Tables("Select").Rows(i).Item("Category_Id")
                Dim SubcategoryId As String = dsSelect.Tables("Select").Rows(i).Item("Subcategory_Id")
                Dim ProductCode As String = dsSelect.Tables("Select").Rows(i).Item("Code")
                Dim ProductTitle As String = dsSelect.Tables("Select").Rows(i).Item("Title")
                Dim ProductDescription As String = dsSelect.Tables("Select").Rows(i).Item("Description")
                Dim ProductMake As String = dsSelect.Tables("Select").Rows(i).Item("Make")
                Dim ProductModel As String = dsSelect.Tables("Select").Rows(i).Item("Model")


                ProductHtml += "<div class=""data-row""><div>" & CategoryId & "</div>" & "<div>" & SubcategoryId & "</div>" & "<div>" & ProductCode & "</div>" & _
                    "<div>" & ProductTitle & "</div>" & "<div><p>" & ProductDescription & "</p></div>" & "<div>" & ProductMake & "</div>" & "<div>" & ProductModel & "</div></div>"

            Next

            response.ClearHeaders()
            response.ContentType = "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
            response.Write(ProductHtml)

        End If


    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean _
            Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Question asked twice and no upvotes or checkboxes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918009/jquery-ajax-post-runs-twice-onclick

Comment: I asked that yesterday, which is a different question and I solved it myself as I said on the UPDATE section.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found something that helped me get towards the answer, so thought i'd put this here in case anyone else has the same issue...hope it helps.

I just needed help on the getting the request information at the url.

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext) Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest


    Dim Request As HttpRequest = context.Request
    Dim Response As HttpResponse = context.Response

    Request.InputStream.Position = 0

    Dim inputStream As New StreamReader(Request.InputStream)

    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim json As String = inputStream.ReadToEnd()
    Dim tst = serializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of Product))(json)


    Dim resp As String = ""
    For Each Prod As Product In tst
        resp += Prod.ProductId & Convert.ToString(" ")
    Next

    Response.ClearHeaders()
    Response.ContentType = "text/html;charset=UTF-8; charset=utf-8"
    Response.Write(resp)


End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

So based on your update, if you just need the data that the jQuery POSTS to your backend VB function, all you need to do is use the Request.Form object instead of the Request.QueryString object. Otherwise, they work exactly the same way.

```
    Dim requestHttp As HttpRequest = context.Request
    Dim UserId As Integer = requestHttp.Form("userid")
    Dim ProductId As Integer = requestHttp.Form("productid")
```

Also, do not forget to fix your javascript:

```
$("[id*='btnProductAdd']").click(function (event) {
    var ProductId = $(this).closest(".product-btn").find("[id*='ProductId']").val();
    AddProduct(81, ProductId);
});

function AddProduct(UserId, ProductId) {

    var ProductInfo = {
        userid: UserId,
        productid: ProductId
    }

    var Url = '/admin/Search.UserProductAdd';

    $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: ProductInfo,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
             console.log('Your return data is here.', data);
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#data').html('Sorry we cannot retreive any data currently, please refresh the page.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but no, it's not on a different domain. I just need help on accessing the data that my code posts to the page http://mydomain.co.uk/admin/Search.UserProductAdd, which is ASP.NET VB 4.5. I've done it using GET before but not POST.

Comment: In my answer, you'll see in the "success" function it returns the 'data' variable. There is a comment that tells you how to view what's in it. Then you can use it just like any variable in javascript.